# Update Mysql records using Ajax/Json isn't working

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, json

What I'm trying to do is to edit mysql records using php. I've used Ajax/Json to edit a single record, but the problem is my codes isn't working. I tried to alert the value of input element after I clicked the save button and the alert output is verified. And also I don't get any message in console.

Here's what I got right now. Any help will appreciate.

Index.php

```
<div class="entry-form1">
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="id_edit" id="id_edit" class="inputs_edit">
<input type="text" name="approved_edit" id="approved_edit" class="inputs_edit">
<input type="submit" name="save_edit" id="save_edit" value="Save"/>
</form>
</div>
```

Search.php

```
$query1 = $mysqli->query(""); // not to include
while($r = $query1->fetch_assoc()){
<td><a href='#' name='".$r['id']."' id='".$r['pr_id']."' class='edits'>Edit</a></td>
}

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

$(".edits").click(function(){
    $(".entry-form1").fadeIn("fast");
    //not to include some parts of codes
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "auto-complete.php",
    data :edit_post_value,
    dataType:'json',
    success:function(data){
    var requested=data.requested;
    var id=data.id;
    //send to element ID
    $('#id_edit').val(id);
    $('#requested_edit').val(requested);
    }
    });

    $("#save_edit").click(function () {
    var two = $('#id_edit').val();
    var five = $('#requested_edit').val();
    alert(five);
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "item_edit.php",
             data: "id_edit="+two+"&requested_edit="+five,
            dataType:'json',
            success: function(data){
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
                if(data.success == "1"){
                        $(".entry-form1").fadeOut("fast");
                    //setTimeout(function(){ window.location.reload(); }, 1000);        
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Item_edit.php

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "app");

if(isset($_POST['id_edit'])) {
$id_edit= $_POST['id_edit'];
$requested_edit= $_POST['requested_edit'];
$sql = $mysqli->query("UPDATE pr_list SET requested='$requested_edit' WHERE id='$id_edit'");

        if($sql){
            echo json_encode(array( "success" => "1"));
        }else{
            echo json_encode(array("success" => "0"));
        }
}
?>
```

Comment: have you got any error messages in console..

Comment: @Gowri That's what I forgot to include to my question. It didn't have any console message.

Comment: your getting value of `requested_edit` on save_edit function  but I didn't see this field in the form.

Comment: Do `$_POST['id_edit']` and `$_POST['requested_edit']` have any values inside `Item_edit.php`?

Comment: @Gowri Pardon me. It has a form. I just forgot to include it here. I updated my question.

Comment: `save_edit(click)` is within `edits(click)` is that intentionally?

Comment: @RST I will discuss that. First I display my mysql records in html table. The table include a link for my edit purposes (class="edits") after that the query will run and post the query results to its designated inputs. That inputs was hiding inside the div="entry-form1". So the value that post into my input elements is what I'm going to update. After save_edit(click) AJAX execute to process another query for update.

Comment: @ekad I don't know if my ajax post the value in Item_edit.php.

Comment: Guess I was right after all. @miso finished it off for you. Glad it is working now.

Comment: @RST yah miso solved my problem. Also thank to you! Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** First, you're not capturing the click event, because **$("# save_edit")** is within a function that is not being called. So, you're not even sending the form to the server.

**2)** Second, the way a form works by default send the data and then reload the page, you must call the **preventDefault()** function from the event object captured to prevent it, before making the ajax call.

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#save_edit").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); //prevent a page reload

        var two = $('#id_edit').val();
        var five = $('#requested_edit').val();
        alert(five);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/item_edit.php",
            data: "id_edit="+two+"&requested_edit="+five,
            dataType:'json',
            success: function(data){

                console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                 if(data.success == "1"){
                            $(".entry-form1").fadeOut("fast");
                        //setTimeout(function(){ window.location.reload(); }, 1000);        
                    }
                }
    });

    });

});
```